# How to maintain API version to provide compatibility and simplicity

Tags: api, backwards-compatibility

I'm designing the API of browser plugin for website. Here are more details:

- user will install browser plugin on user's machine, the plugin will be upgraded in future. e.g. adobe flash is a plugin for web browser.
- our website will launch the plugin, and use the API exposed from plugin. e.g. use the API to draw some graphics on plugin canvas.

The problem I'm try to resolve with the API version:

- in future different user may have different version of plugin installed. because when upgrade the plugin, there must be some of users not upgraded yet when access our website. So user A may installed plugin 1.0, and user B may have plugin 1.1, user C may have 1.2.
- we are going to have one website for all the users, so it's website's responsibility to handle different version of API when loading plugin.
- website is composed of multiple modules, we may upgrade module A and use latest version of plugin API and then released it. In the meanwhile Module B may still use older version of plugin API.

My initial solution:

- make the maximum compatibility of API, but we may still remove deprecated functions for simplicity.
- when use API, the website modules will use something like var obj = plugin.api("1.0"), or plugin.api("1.1") to get a specific version of API to use. Modules can change the version it used when upgrade. a specific version of "obj" will be consistent, but 1.0 and 1.1 may be different. (a little bit similar with COM interface)

The issue to the initial solution:

- Plugin should maintain different version of API inside, and provide compatibility. This will introduce the complexity of plugin internal implementation.
- website should still need to handle the case that plugin on user's machine are not providing the required version of API.

Any suggestions/comments?

Comment: I don't see a good reason for the *plugins* contain multiple versions of the APIs- after all the only website using the plugin will be yours, right? So you could always leverage the latest version of the plugin's API, by using version checks on the server side, then executing that specific version of the site. Alternatively, you could have the plugin try to update itself when it detects it's an old version, and then you'd only need to maintain the current version of the API (not necessarily possible for all scenarios).

Comment: @Kitsune Yes. Our website will be the only one to use the plugin, and upgrade mechanism has been added to the plugin, we provided 2 way to upgrade the plugin, one is to automatically check for update, even the plugin not loaded, another one is to trigger the update from JavaScript. Another reason that we need to handle multiple version is API is: in order to control the risks, we deliver a new update to a small part of users first, and monitor for several days, if there are no significant regressions/issues, then issue a formal update on server to trigger auto-update for all users.